# Why isn't snowsql opening an external browser?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get `snowsql` working locally on my machine but I cannot log into my database because it requires that I authenticate with my google account for SSO.  The documentation says to use the `--authenticator externalbrowser` option which *should* open a local browser and ask me to sign on but that doesn't happen, nothing happens.

Example:

```sh
$ snowsql -o log_level=DEBUG -a <account> -u <gmail> --authenticator externalbrowser
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...
```

No browser windows open.  Pressing `CTRL+C` does not abort snowsql; I must run pkill to kill it.  The last of my logs show

```
2021-06-17 14:48:12,211 (222954/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:940  - SUCCESS
2021-06-17 14:48:12,212 (222954/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:1096 - Active requests sessions: 0, idle: 1
2021-06-17 14:48:12,212 (222954/MainThread) snowflake.connector.network DEBUG        network:642  - ret[code] = None, after post request
2021-06-17 14:48:12,212 (222954/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth_webbrowser DEBUG auth_webbrowser:123  - step 2: open a browser
2021-06-17 14:48:12,237 (222954/MainThread) snowflake.connector.auth_webbrowser DEBUG auth_webbrowser:136  - step 3: accept SAML token
```

platform:

- Platform is Arch Linux (kernel version 5.12.10)
- Default browser is `BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox`
- `snowsql --version` says 1.2.15
- Installed via [snowflake-client](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/snowflake-client/) AUR package. (Which currently says version 1.2.14 but I believe `snowsql` updated itself to 1.2.15.)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are running the latest SnowSQL version and also provide the OS that you are running SnowSQL on?  Also, what is your default browser?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, where does the log get saved when you use =o log_level=DEBUG? (on Windows)

Comment: @datamonk3y I had to set the log path in `~/.snowsql/config` to `~/.local/share/snosql.log` because it was defaulting to `../snowsql.log` which could be `/home/snowsql.log` which it couldn't write to.

Comment: @MikeWalton version `1.2.15`, `BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox` platform is Arch Linux installed using this package https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/snowflake-client/ .  Which is on 1.2.14 but the snowsql binary updated itself.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you see different behavior if you already have a browser session open?

Comment: @MikeWalton No. It doesn't matter if my browser is opened or closed.  I've also tried other browsers  like chromium.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not a Linux expert, so not sure I can assist you further.  You might want to reach out to Snowflake Support and see if they have a solution for you.  I'm not entirely sure that the externalbrowser supports Linux environments, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: For me I had to update snowsql, and also I had to to unset BROWSER

Comment: Having the same on macOS 12.3.1 (apple silicon), `snowsql` 1.2.21

Comment: Is there a Snowflake bug issue on this - that would probably have a better chance of making things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70015693/2340690) for why snowsql isn't working.  tl;dr it bundles it's own version of libz and doesn't use the system's version when opening your browser.

Based on that answer I concocted a little script to replace the bundled libz with the system libz.  You'll need to run it whenever snowflake updates.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VERSION=$(snowsql --version | cut -d' ' -f2)
LIBS="$HOME/.snowsql/$VERSION"
LIBZ="$LIBS/libz.so.1"
if ! [[ -L $LIBZ ]]
then
  mv -v $LIBZ{,-bak}
fi
SYSTEM=$(sudo find /usr -name libz.so* 2> /dev/null | head -n1)
ln -sfv $SYSTEM $LIBZ
```

Comment: In my case, there is no `libz.so.1` but only `libz.so` in the system folder. soft link `libz.so` to `libz.so.1` works for me. `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so ~/.snowsql/1.2.24/libz.so.1`

Answer (score 2):

for me, setting the --region flag solved it, even though it's deprecated, according to the official [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html)

Answer (score 0):

spcvalente's solution worked for me... I have no idea why.

I added the `--region us-east-1` flag and it all worked.

My full command was

`snowsql -a {my account ID} -u {my user} --authenticator externalbrowser --region us-east-1`

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35839318)