# snowsql --authenticator=externalbrowser error using firefox+ubuntu

Tags: linux, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, zlib

I get the following when I attempt to login using the snowsql client using an external browser.

> /home/username/.snowsql/1.2.16/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
> Couldn't load XPCOM.

Here is my OS info

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="21.04"
ID=pop
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 21.04"
VERSION_ID="21.04"
HOME_URL="https://pop.system76.com"
SUPPORT_URL="https://support.system76.com"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://system76.com/privacy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hirsute
UBUNTU_CODENAME=hirsute
LOGO=distributor-logo-pop-os
```

Comment: this is rather  a linux system issue. which version of ubuntu are you on? if you are on old version of ubuntu , try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306849/lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libz-so-1-version-zlib-1-2-9-not-found)

Comment: Thanks. I am running 21.04, although I was having issues with 20.04 prior to upgrading. @eshirvana

Comment: I tried creating a simlink to libz.so.1 as recommended in .snowsql/1.2.16/, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 21.04 and it's shipped with zlib 1.2.11 ( latest version) so I assume you have to downgrade it , probably have to uninstall that version first ( not sure if there is any dependency on that, so you have to make sure of that)  and then follow the steps.

Comment: I guess you need to download the ZLib,install it and then test again. Something like this. :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306849/lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libz-so-1-version-zlib-1-2-9-not-found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Snowsql overrides LD_PRELOAD for its own bundling mechanism, and doesn't bother to unset it when it tries to start your browser.

This means your browser tries to use libs bundled with snowsql instead of your system libs.

You can "fix" by removing the libs bundled with SnowSQL that are causing issues (at least libz, libselinux for me) and replacing them with symlinks to those from your own platform:

```sh
cd ~/.snowsql/1.2.20
rm libz.so.1 libselinux.so.1
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 ./
```

Bug has been raised with Snowflake, they confirmed and reproduced, but this was months ago and I haven't heard anything since.

You might also say this is caused be SnowSQL bundling a version of zlib that it looks like first made it into Debian in 2005? I'm sure they have been very diligent about backporting security fixes, there's nothing to worry about here.

Comment: Thanks! This looks really promising.

Comment: In 1.2.23, there's no `libselinux.so.1`